# Pdf doesn't appear

Tags: pdf, compiling

I've already installed Texstudio to windows10 but the pdf doesn't appear to me when I compile a tex file.

the only arquives that was shown to me are:

[image]

how can i fix it?

edit: How can i organize this section?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems you have a `.dvi` file (it is kind of a precursor of `.pdf`), which means you are running `latex` instead of `pdflatex`.  Search in TeXStudio an option to typeset your document with `pdflatex` instead of `latex`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, i get it! Now the pdf is on.

Comment: Phelype, can you explain to me how can i organize this? I put the image in the answer's section.

Comment: ok i organized the question

Comment: Thanks Luiza! Though I still don't understand what you mean with “How can I organize this section”.  Could you clarify, please?